# Fibonacci Cycles Back...Figure out the Fibonacci Number FBN

Tags: mathematics

$Given$:

$F$, $B$, $N$, $U$, $V$ are all digits that can vary from 0 to 9..but not necessarily distinct.

$FBN$, $NBF$, $UV$, $VU$ are all concatenated numbers.

From information given below, what is $FBN$?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution

> $F=U=1$, $V=2$, $N=B=4$

Reasoning

> $144 = 12^2$ and $441=21^2$ and $FBN=144$ is a Fibonacci number.

Alternative,

> It's easy to show that the above is the only solution with $F>0$ as there are only five Fibonacci numbers between $100$ and $1000$ and only one is a square. If we also allow $F=0$ then there are two other possible solutions.
>  $$F=B=U=0, V=N=1$$
>  $$F=B=U=V=N=0 $$
>  These would satisfy the constraints given that the reversal strictly implies a $3$-digit reversal at the top and a $2$-digit reversal at the bottom.

Comment: 121 is not a fibonacci

Comment: @Uvc sorry I missed that requirement, updated now.

Comment: That’s much better...